# Many picture overlap on screen in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My cursor move on screen while open Android Studio.
Picture screen Overlap.
What happen ? and How can I fix them ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Restart android studio

Comment: do You have the required hardware specifications http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, you just have to reconfigure your monitor settings to detect only one screen, neither duplicate screen, nor expand screen, just reconfigure to show in one screen, your main screen.

**UPDATE:** other way, you can update your Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

its overlap because of your previous selection you can just reset it by Shift + F12 or Window >> Restore Default Layout

Comment: I try restore default layout but it overlap again.

Comment: i don't think so there is any another way to reset you can check if your computer is virus infected...